# MySql php no data returned

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying a simple php example to confirm data retrieval from a MySql database and I'm not seeing any data returned, but also no specific error either. Any advice for what to try next will be greatly appreciated!

---

I have a local MySql db as well as an internet web site instance and they are both doing the same thing ... which is ... I can connect to the mysql server, then connect to the database, but the sql result has no data.

Viewing over the respective db's I can see the table and data.  I've not previously seen a failure running a valid query after connecting to the server and db.

Locally I'm using VS2012 with a php tool ([DEVSENSE](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5/)) and on the internet web site I've created the below php file and am accessing it via web address.

The following is the php file ... note that I've added some additional output to show the contents of some of the variables.

```
<body>

    <form>        
            <?php

            $mysqlserver="localhost";
            $mysqlusername="user";
            $mysqlpassword="mypassword";
            $mysqldatabase="mydata";

$link = mysql_connect($mysqlserver, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}


if ($link) {

echo '<a>MySql db link= ' . $link . '</a><br>';
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($mysqldatabase, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
      echo '<select id="Error" name="err">';
      echo '<option value="Error"></option>';
      echo '</select>';
      die ('<a> Can\'t use database: ' . $mysqldatabase . '</a>');
}

  echo '<a>database= ' . $mysqldatabase . '</a><br>';

  $sql = sprintf("SELECT Location FROM `myLocations` Order by Location");

  echo '<a>sql= ' . $sql . '</a><br>';

  $result = mysql_query($link, $sql);

  echo '<a>result= ' . $result . '</a><br>';

  if (!$Result) {
      echo '<label>Locations (none) &nbsp;</label>';
      echo '<select id="Error" name="err">';
      echo '<option value="Error"></option>';
      echo '</select>';
      die ("<a>Error: (" . mysql_errno($link) . "): " . mysql_error($link) . "</a>");
      }

   echo '<label>Locations</label>&nbsp;';
   echo '<select name="selectedLocation">';
   echo '<option value=""></option>';

   $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
   for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++) {
       $row = mssql_fetch_array($result);
       $name = $row['name'];
       echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name. '</option>';
   }

   echo '</select>';

   mysql_close($link);
}

?>
    </form>

</body>
```

---

Here's a sample returned result page using the above php file:

> MySql db link= Resource id #2
> database= mydata
> sql= SELECT Location FROM `myLocations` Order by Location
> result= 
> Locations (none)  Error: (0):

---

Here's the generated schema for table 'myLocations'

```
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Table mydata_mylocations
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'mydata'.`mylocations` (
  `Id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `Location` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `IsActive` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `AsOfDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Comment: You're selecting `myLocations` as the table, but you created one with `mylocations`. In some systems, lettercase matters. Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` see if it returns any errors. That could be irrelevant; however, you're mixing APIs using `mssql_fetch_array` which should be `mysql_fetch_array`. Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.

Comment: Thanks @Fred -ii-. I've correct the typos. I did try the replacement of mysql_error() with mysql_query() and that unfortunately shows nothing... which is the same result as $Result.  So with the typos cleaned up, I'm still getting the same result of no data.  I did also tried a replacement from mysql_ to mysqli_ and that failed at the first function call... so I'm stuck for what is happening.  I conclude that there isn't anything obviously wrong with my php code, but there's something else under the covers... maybe SSL with my web site retrieval (but that doesn't apply to my local instance)

Comment: You're welcome. See if by adding error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` will yield anything.

Comment: Thank you again @Fred-ii-!  There were two errors in my script.  1. $result and $Result are not the same and the mySql_Query had the parameters in reverse order, and $row['name'] should have been $row['Location']! Showing me the display errors functions was the key!  Thank you very much!  I'm getting data now! Woohoo!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it was resolved, *cheers!*